# Можно ли подключиться py-скриптом к открытой https-сессии фаерфокса?

Tags: python, https, tls

Пишу скрипт, который должен просить у https-сайта json-информацию. На сайте есть регистрация, которую я выполняю в браузере. Далее, практически каждый запрос в браузере порождает 2 соединения: первое типа CONNECT - устанавливается тунель с веб-сервером "привет сервер, дай/обнови мою сессию и тикет", второй - непосредственно POST-запрос "дай мне такие-то данные". Ок, я беру полученный user_id, который использует браузер для запросов, подключаю нужные заголовки, куки и подставляю это все в скрипт через requests.Session() => post(..., verify=False) - получаю ответ 200, но без json-данных.
Меняю verify на True - ошибки:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

..те созданная сессия в скрипте не содержит тех данных, которые есть в сессии браузера. Кроме того логи говорят о том, что скрипт стучится на сервер по HTTP/1.0, а нужно через 1.1 вот так..

```
CONNECT target.com:443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
Host: target.com:443

A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
Random: 9D C7 9D 23 3F D1 A0 17 90 44 A0 AE 25 55 9B 7E 26 ED 31 1D D5 70 F9 A2 BC 4B 94 6B 32 E6 B1 A1
"Time": 08/12/1988 2.06.53
SessionID: D8 05 00 00 58 26 47 AD D5 43 A7 DE DC A7 4C 15 FE 77 40 05 F4 C5 24 AC 5C 7B 46 76 D1 24 61 E8
Extensions: 
    server_name target.com
    extended_master_secret  empty
    renegotiation_info  00
    elliptic_curves secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18], secp521r1 [0x19]
    ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
    SessionTicket   empty
    NextProtocolNego    empty
    ALPN        h2, spdy/3.1, http/1.1
    status_request  OCSP - Implicit Responder
    signature_algs  sha256_rsa, sha384_rsa, sha512_rsa, sha1_rsa, sha256_ecdsa, sha384_ecdsa, sha512_ecdsa, sha1_ecdsa, sha256_dsa, sha1_dsa
Ciphers: 
    [C02B]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C02F]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [CCA9]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    [CCA8]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    [C00A]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C009]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C013]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C014]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [0033]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA
    [0039]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA
    [0035]  TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA
    [000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION
```

В ответ на такой запрос сервер браузеру присылает такой ответ:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 21.10.02.820
Connection: close

Encrypted HTTPS traffic flows through this CONNECT tunnel. HTTPS Decryption is enabled in Fiddler, so decrypted sessions running in this tunnel will be shown in the Web Sessions list.

Secure Protocol: Tls
Cipher: Aes 256bits
Hash Algorithm: Sha1 160bits
Key Exchange: ECDHE_RSA (0xae06) 256bits

== Server Certificate ==========
[Subject]
  CN=*.target.com, OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard, OU=Domain Control Validated

[Issuer]
  CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford, S=Greater Manchester, C=GB

[Serial Number]
  00CC7F2093507FB207C688867166E5E115

[Not Before]
  27/07/2016 2.00.00

[Not After]
  26/09/2018 1.59.59

[Thumbprint]
  EEAD7408E980E2A63242A937EAC13DCFB31696C6

[SubjectAltNames]
*.target.com, target.com
```

..те, скриптом я не могу получить SessionID и сертификат от сервера для продолжения диалога, хотя использую все заголовки и куки. Может есть возможность использовать полученные браузером данные сессии в скрипте? Возможно нужно делать и авторизацию на сайте скриптом..=/

Comment: у тебя  три варианта 1) разбираться что ты там неправильно делаешь и каких данных нехватает 2) скриптовать firefox на js 3) воспользоваться чем-нибудь типа http://pyxpcomext.mozdev.org/, при желании можешь даже собрать headless-версию (без графической морды) firefox с этим плагином :3

Comment: О, новые слова, благодарю..=) Тут https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/browsercookie дядька вроде как тащит браузерные куки в скрипт, вот я и подумал, может есть такая штука и про Сессии.. =)

Comment: Есть три вещи, которые никак не связаны: 1- прокси, к которой вы http CONNECT запрос делаете 2- https запрос к конечному сайту и валидность его ssl-сертификата  и 3- сессия на сайте на уровне приложения, например подкреплённая куками (не имеет никакого отношения к "открытой https-сессии фаерфокса", чтобы это выражение ни значило (я сомневаюсь, что вы хотите MitM на себя самого провести)). Чтобы с деталями не возиться, можете попробовать selenium webdriver или Ghost.py. Если хотите возиться с деталями, то начните с SSLError

Comment: Я понял, все сложно.